# Line break in the UITableViewCell

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin

I have a `UITableViewCell` with a `UILabel` that I need to display multiple lines per cell.

Can anyone tell what I have to do?
Because I'm not getting.
Thank you.

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier); 
    if (cell == null)
        cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, cellIdentifier);
    cell.TextLabel.Lines = 0;
    cell.TextLabel.SizeToFit ();
    cell.TextLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
    cell.TextLabel.Text = wodsFemininos [indexPath.Row].Nome;
    cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = wodsFemininos [indexPath.Row].Masculino;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the UI you want to build ?

Comment: You'll need to use a custom cell and layout the label by yourself.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom cell (with XIB) and use a UITextView to use some lines

```
import UIKit
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell{

@IBOutlet weak var text: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var detail: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

}
class func cellId() -> String{
    return "CustomCell"
}
```

}

and now in TableView methods

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CustomCell.cellId() , forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

cell.text.text = wodsFemininos [indexPath.Row].Nome;
cell.detail.text = wodsFemininos [indexPath.Row].Masculino;

return cell;
}
```

Comment: fwiw, this question was tagged C#.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at this sample code:
https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/GrowRowTable

Documentation on implementation:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/autosizing-row-height/

It will have the xib and autolayout constraints you need to achieve this.

> **GrowRowTable**
>
> Starting with iOS 8, Apple added the ability to create a Table View (UITableView) that can automatically grow and shrink the height of a give Row based on the size of it's content using Auto Layout, Size Classes and Constraints.
>
> This sample shows how to create a Table View with Auto-Resizing Row Height.

looks like this:

[image]